# Laravel - SQL - SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'nsfw' at row 1

Tags: mysql, laravel, checkbox

I'm trying to safe some data in my database and get the following error:

SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'nsfw' at row 1

The nsfw column has a 0 as a standart value. Thats my table:

[image: phpmyadminscreenshot]

The nsfw column is also in the models `$fillable` array.

I want to detect if a checkbox is checked. If it is checked, nsfw should be 1. If it's not, nsfw should be 0.

Thats the checkbox HTML code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
             <label for="nsfw" class="control-label">NSFW</label>
             <br>
             <input type="checkbox" name="nsfw">
  </div>
```

And thats the controller code:

```
 if (Input::get('nsfw')) {
       $nsfw = true;
 } else {
       $nsfw = false;
 }

 // dd($nsfw) gives me true or 
 //false back, depending if the checkbox is checked or not

 $thread = new Thread();
 $thread->name = Input::get('thread-name');
 $thread->description = Input::get('thread-desc');
 $thread->age_min = Input::get('thread-min-age');
 $thread->age_max = Input::get('thread-max-age');
 if ($nsfw == true) {
     $thread->nsfw = 1;
 } else {
     $thread->nsfw = 0;
 }
 $thread->save();
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: you have an enum and you insert a value not present in the enum

Comment: but the only possible values are 1 or 0. And thats what I want to push into the databse or not?

Comment: go to config/database.php in the connections.mysql  set strict to false, then try to run it again, if u got no errors check if u have the data inserted correctly

Comment: okay I did that and the thread get's saved. But in the database the value is just Null. not 0.

Comment: try to make the value on the code as string $thread->nsfw = '1';

Comment: ah, yeah, works perfect! Please write a answer, so I can vote it for the right answer :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to `config/database.php` in the `connections.mysql` set strict to false, then try to run it again, if you have no errors check if you have the data inserted correctly. If you don't then you are entering the wrong type of data to the mentioned column, so set your code to store values as strings:

```
if ($nsfw == true) {
  $thread->nsfw = '1';
} else {
  $thread->nsfw = '0';
}
```

Comment: Just check your insert value is same your enum value? There is strictly compare by enum. ex... you put true value in enum and you insert 1 then its not accepting by enum type. +1

Answer (score 3):

When strict mode is true and you get errors, it means you have other errors in the code, for example a wrong datatype or a spelling error.

Leo's answer is right. I just want to emphasis, that you should reset the strict mode to true again.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the database column for spelling mistakes for that, or `enum` value exists in the col.

Answer (score -1):

The data is truncated because you use a comma (,) when input data, try not to use a comma in the data to be input.

this my error :

SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'D01' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `mbs` (`kodepertanyaan`, `D01`, `D02`, `D03`, `D04`, `D05`, `D06`, `D07`) values (drg, 0,7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

I try to input 0,7

Comment: Your example is not related to this question aside from them both tossing the same error. His problem was "string" vs Number for a boolean field being Enumerated instead of Boolean. Yours is not that problem. Good try, might help someone with this error, but not this particular question.