# Enum value does not get inserted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a table called `clients` and goes like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('user_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
            $table->string('email_address')->nullable()->unique();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->enum('registration_process', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And I want to insert data like this:

```
public function stepOne(Request $request)
    {
        $validData = $request->validate([
            'phone' => ['required','unique:clients,phone_number']
        ]);

        $client = Client::create([
            'phone_number' => "0".$validData['phone'],
            'registration_process' => 0
        ]);

        return redirect(route('client.login'));
    }
```

As you can see I have set the `registration_process'` to **`0`** but the problem is it returns this error:

**SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'registration_process' at row 1**

And as the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018780/laravel-sql-sqlstate01000-warning-1265-data-truncated-for-column-nsfw) question says, I tried setting `false` for `strict` in `mysql.connections` at `database.php` and after that tried one more time and this time, the error was gone but the data did not gets inserted and it's set to *empty* somehow:

[image]

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

---

**UPDATE:**

[image]

```
127.0.0.1/digipayesh/clients/       http://localhost/phpmyadmin/tbl_sql.php?db=digipayesh&table=clients
Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

show create table `clients`



clients CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigne...
```

Comment: Set up query logging on your database and see what's being passed. Check how the table was created and ensure it has appropriate values. Aren't `ENUM` columns generally considered strings?

Comment: Considering what miken32 said, does `'registration_process' => '0'` work?

Comment: Can you please post the full output of the `show create table` statement as **text**?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes but I don't know how to do that, plz would u help me, I'm really stuck with this...

Comment: You can normally select all text dragging the mouse over it and then copy to clipboard with the right mouse button. To paste, trigger the right button menu in the question's text area. It's actually simpler than taking a screenshot.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I just copied to clipboard and pasted in the question,  is that the right output?

Comment: Is `registration_process` in the `$fillable` array in the model?

Comment: The important information is the SQL code to create the `registration_process` column, which is seemingly hidden after the `…` ellipsis. It's just a quick check to verify that the up migration generated the expected column—the problem may perfectly be somewhere else.

Comment: @D1__1 I have added `protected $guarded = [];`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) (emphasis mine):

> An `ENUM` is a ***string*** object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.

So you'll want to set up your column like this:

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('user_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
            $table->string('email_address')->nullable()->unique();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->enum('registration_process', ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I would then add the column to the model's `$casts` array to ensure it's passed as a string to the database:

```php
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        "registration_process" => "string",
    ];
}
```

You'll want to adjust your logic anywhere you might be treating the value as an integer for comparison purposes, e.g. `if ($client->registration_status === 1)...`

Comment: I just tried what you told , but still get the same error

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE clients`

Comment: I just added it as **UPDATE**, plz check it out

Comment: That's not very helpful. What is the actual output of the command from the mysql command line? As text, not an image.

Comment: I don't how to show the proper output of the command, the field is not expandable !

Comment: Use `php artisan db` to get to mysql command line.